# Firebase: Get the first result and update it

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, ionic3

I would like to create into Firebase an "AccountQueues" object that will have account and names or the word "FREE" if it doesn't have account.

AccountQueues
  -LEf-OrdKi65WG0NkQSG
   AccountID: 
    "GR215"
    Name: 
     "FREE"

When a user register I would like to take the first FREE AccountID and update it with the name of the user. Thank you for your help. I am developing an ionic 3 mobile app with this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a query to check for an account that is free and limit it to the first search result. You want to use snapshotChanges() in order to return the key of the object.

```
    returnedKey = null;

    this.fireDB.list('AccountQueues', ref => ref.orderByChild('Name').equalTo('FREE').limitToFirst(1)).snapshotChanges().take(1).subscribe(res => {

    res.map(doc => {

    this.returnedKey = doc.key; //use this key to update object

        });

    });
```

Using the returned key from the query you can then update that object

```
this.fireDB.object(`AccountQueues/${this.returnedKey}`).update({Name:'Bob'});
```